# Display issue with radeditor ToolbarMode="ShowOnFocus" and symbols

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radeditor

I have an editor defined very simply as below.  The editor is within the footer of grids and the toolbar definition contains the 'InsertSymbol' tool.  When I click the InsertSymbol tool the popup to select my symbol appears way up in the top corner of my page and the toolbar disappears. See screenshot, the black circled textbox is radeditor, symbol popup circled in red.  If I remove the ShowOnFocus toolbar mode this behaviour seems to go away and the popup appears where expected.

Can anyone tell me how to position the popup near the editor in this scenario?  I really do not want to remove the 'ShowOnFocus' setting as the additional toolbars clutter up the page quite badly when they are only used rarely.

```
  <telerik:RadEditor ID="txtLevel1TextFooter" runat="server" ToolsFile="~/Seminar/Agenda/ImportToolsDetail.xml"
                                ToolbarMode="ShowOnFocus" Height="25px" OnClientLoad="OnClientLoad" EditModes="Design"
                                StripFormattingOptions="MSWordRemoveAll" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the folloing KB article which demonstrates how to load the editor's dialogs at the desired position on the page.

http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/editor/setting-dialog-pop-up-position.aspx